# UDP Send File Exact Number of Bytes

Tags: c, udp

I'm writing a toy client/server app and sending data over a UDP stream. Everything is working well when I send small messages like "test" or something like that. But when I go to transfer files, I seem to be transferring too much data.

The file that I am transferring is a little less than 4k in size (at least according to an ls command). But when my sendto operation completes, my confirmation message shows that I have sent exactly 5000 bytes (which is the max size of my buffer).

I'd rather not break the sendto up if I don't need to since UDP can potentially transfer messages out of order. Anyone see what I am doing wrong? I think that is has to do with my use of `sizeof(buffer)`, but I don't know how to transfer exactly the number of bytes that I want. Thank you!

Here is the relevant part of the code. Please let me know if you need more:

```
char buffer[5000];
char path[] = "myfile";

FILE* fp;
if ((fp = fopen(path, "rb")) == NULL) {
    printf(stdout, "Error opening the file: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}

memset(&buffer[0], 0, sizeof(buffer));
do {
    fread(buffer, 1, MAXBUFSIZE, fp);
} while (!feof(fp));

if ( (numbytes = sendto(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0,
        (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr))) < 0)
{
    perror("send error");    
}

fprintf(stderr, "client sent %d bytes to server\n", numbytes);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the sendto command, UDP will send the same amount of data as specified in the send length; the third param is the send length: http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendto . The example is specifying sizeof(buffer) as the send length and sizeof(buffer) is 5000. Accordingly, UDP sends 5000 bytes from the buffer (which is actually the entire buffer). If we want to send the exact number of bytes as present in the file, then we should read the number of bytes in the file, and pass that as the send length.

```
numbytes = sendto(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0,
```

Comment: You're right. I suspected that was the problem, but I didn't know how to get the file size. After a little more reading, I realized that fread returns the file size (in this case), so I think that I have it. Thanks!